# Show user profile images on top of the custom annotation

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit, mkannotationview

I was able to add a custom annotation image to replace the default marker, but I can't figure out how to add the user image on top of it. I need the user image to load from a URL.

p.s. I need an iOS 7 solution.

This is basically what I want to achieve (taken from another app):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

Added a UIImageView as subview to the MKAnnotationView:

```
MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-map-placemark-68x80"];
pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, -5);

UIImageView *profileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
profileImageView.frame = CGRectMake(6, 7, 55, 55);
profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 27;          
[profileImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/avatar.jpg"]];

[pinView addSubview:profileImageView];
```

p.s. To display image from URL I'm using the SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h category.